# Unable to Access Resource drawable from dynamic-feature module/OnDemand Feature module

Tags: java, kotlin

I am trying to Add Android Dynamic feature module to my App, the purpose of this module is to provide drawable dynamically to reduce app size. But my attempts to access the resources of the dynamic feature module keep failing. Sometimes drawable are accessed after installing OnDemand module and restarting app again, and sometimes they are not accessed.
To get drawable, I have defined an extension function.

```
fun Context.moduleRes(drawable_name: String):Drawable?{
    val featureModuleName = "assets"
    val refreshedContext = createPackageContext(packageName, 0)
    val packageNameWitFeatureModule = "${applicationContext.packageName}.$featureModuleName"

    val drawableId = refreshedContext.resources.getIdentifier(
        drawable_name, "drawable", packageNameWitFeatureModule
    )
    return if (drawableId!=0){
        val drawable = refreshedContext.getDrawable(drawableId)
        drawable
    }else{
        resources.getDrawable(R.drawable.icl_youtube_icon)
    }
}
```

I've read through the Android Docs that are provided by Google but I'm not able to find detailed information about how to access a downloaded modules recourses.

https://developer.android.com/codelabs/on-demand-dynamic-delivery#4